# I am trying to get the membercount of my server in my Discord bot's status

Tags: discord.js

Title - I don't have much experience and don't know where to start.

I have looked at many examples which haven't proved to be helpful - any help/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `<guild>.memberCount`, which returns the number of your total members.

Docs for it are found here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount

Answer (score 0):

```
var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
```

Read the documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount). (Thanks Squiddleton)

I started programming Discord bots just a few months back, quite intriguing.

As for beginners, I would suggest going through [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-discord-bot-with-node-js) *just for a headstart* and then taking off yourself after learning the basics of discord.js and node.js.

If you face any issues while doing the same, you can ask your questions on Stack Overflow or search it on Google - you will find a lot of questions directly on the web.

> The only reason why I wouldn't suggest Youtube tutorials for making Discord bots or programming anything is that **it starts to turn into a habit** and suppresses our natural instincts of discovering things. And trust me, discovering things yourself helps you **a lot** in the long run.

Even if you direly need to watch a video tutorial, try to pick up the basics from it and discover things, it's a lot more fun and the experience gained is incredible.